# Como Obter as propriedade do Jquery validate

Tags: javascript

Estou com uma duvida sobre o validate do Jquery. consigo usar ele normalmente. porem preciso de uma validação caso o usuário escolha uma opção no formulário "SELECT > OPTION", tenho duas opção, "SIM","NÃO". Se o usuário escolhe "SIM" vai aparecer outro campo para ele preencher-lo, mais ta ai minha duvida, não estou conseguindo muda o attributo do rules do campos que não era obrigatório, para TRUE, caso ele clique em cadastrar e ele não tenha digitado nesse campos que apareceu.

Alguém ai tem uma sugestão, mais quero continuar usando o Jquery validate:

Aqui esta o meu Codigo JQuery:

```js
$('#form-visitantes').validate({
rules: {
nomecompleto: {required: true},
sexo: {required: true},
fone: {required: true},
email: {required: true},
foi_convidado: {required: false} // esse campos nao e obrigatorio, ele so aparece no formulario caso o usuario informe fui convidado
},
messages: {
nomecompleto: {required: 'Campo Obrigatório'},
sexo: {required: 'Campo Obrigatório'},
fone: {required: 'Campo Obrigatório'},
email: {required: 'Campo Obrigatório'},
foi_convidado: {required: 'Campo Obrigatório'}

},
submitHandler: function (form) {
var dados = $(form).serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: URL_POST,
    data: dados,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) {
if (data.retorno === true) {
$(".msg-result").html('<div class="bg-success text-center p-20">' + data.mensagem + '</div>');
    document.getElementById("form-visitantes").reset();
} else {
$(".msg-result").html('<div class="bg-danger text-center p-20">' + data.mensagem + '</div>');
}
    }
});
return false;
},
errorClass: "text-danger",
errorElement: "span",
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
$(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('text-danger');
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
$(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('text-danger');
$(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('success');
}
});
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Percebi que está criando múltiplas perguntas para um mesmo problema, quando isso na verdade não vai lhe ajudar a conseguir uma resposta mais depressa, ao invés disso leia o guia [ask] e o faça um [tour], para aprender um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento do site para assim aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)).

Comment: Quando quiser colocar uma pergunta em evidencia faça uma edição que ela automaticamente vai para o topo da lista.

Comment: Remova essa questão. Como as duas estão em evidencia pode acontecer de fecharem as duas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery validate (Rules)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/426899/jquery-validate-rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o método `.rules()` do **[Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/)** para remover ou adicionar o `required` ao campo. Você pode fazer isso com o método `.change()` do select.

Por exemplo, o código `elemento.rules("remove", "required")` remove o `required` do campo, já o `elemento.rules("add", "required")` readiciona o `required`.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
$("[name='convidado']").change(function(){
   $("[name='foi_convidado']")
   .attr("type", this.value == "nao" ? "hidden" : "text")
   .rules(this.value == "nao" ? "remove" : "add", "required");
   
   if(this.value == "nao"){
      $("#foi_convidado-error").remove();
   }
   
});

$('#form-visitantes').validate({
   rules: {
      foi_convidado: {required: false} // esse campos nao e obrigatorio, ele so aparece no formulario caso o usuario informe fui convidado
   },
   messages: {
      foi_convidado: {required: 'Campo Obrigatório'}
   },
   submitHandler: function (form) {
      console.log("form enviado");
   }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="form-visitantes">
   <select name="convidado">
      <option value="nao">Não</option>
      <option value="sim">Sim</option>
   </select>
   <input name="foi_convidado" type="hidden">
   <div class="msg-result"></div>
   <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Sam, agora entendi!